# C# MVC Routemap and Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building an MVC web application. I want to create a custom url of login to some page in my site, for example:

> www.mysite.com/sites/mycompany/mysite/GetLogin/myusername

so I create a new MapRouteas as the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "GetLogin", // the Route name
            "sites/{company}/{site}/{action}/{username}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "GetLogin" },
            new[] { "****.Controllers" }
        );
```

And in the Home controller I have the GetLogin action result:

```
public ActionResult GetLogin()
{
        string UserName = Request.QueryString["username"];
        if (UserName != null)
        {

        }
        return View();    
}
```

but the value of UserName variable is null, and i didn't found where is the problem.

Comment: Change the method to `public ActionResult GetLogin(string company, string site, string username)` - you using route values, not query string values

Comment: Thanks, it's work by this way. but if i want to use querystring, what i need to change in the route?

Comment: Why would you want to do that - your url would need to be `.../Home/GetLogin?company=someValue&site=someValue&username=someValue` (and delete the route definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a part of `QueryString`.It is part of `RouteData`.`QueryString` will contain everything after `?` symbol which means the parameters passed by query string.But in your route you give it as a block of **route**.So You can retrieve it from `RouteData`

```
public ActionResult GetLogin()
{
        string UserName = RouteData.Values.Contains("username") ? RouteData.Values["username"].ToString() : null;
        if (UserName != null)
        {

        }
        return View();    
}
```

**Reply to comment**

For QueryString it must have a look like

*www.mysite.com/sites/mycompany/mysite/GetLogin?username*

and root

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "GetLogin", // the Route name
            "sites/{company}/{site}/{action}", 
            new { controller = "Home" },
            new[] { "****.Controllers" }
        );
```

Comment: Ok, you right, so if i want to use query string, how?

Comment: Thanks! and how does my route map needs to be?

Comment: @TomerA see post.But it a very very bad to do like this.I suggest you to work with RouteValue not query string

Comment: unfortunately it is not working.. here is the url I tried::
****/sites/mycompany/mysite/GetLogin?username=tomer
and the querystring is null..